# Sqlite, subtracting a date entity from current time

Tags: database, linux, sqlite, timestamp, strftime

I have a table which have entries like this.

```
SELECT entrydate FROM entities;

2013-04-29 13:24:34
2013-04-29 13:24:46
2013-04-29 13:27:19
```

What I want to do is that taking difference between current date and these entities.
I try

```
SELECT strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s', entrydate) FROM entities;
-7881
-7893
-8046
```

It returns negative values although current timestamp should be bigger than entities.

I compared `strftime('%s','now')` and `date +%s` outputs and saw they are same.

I figured out that  `strftime('%s', entrydate)` returns bigger value than it should be. How can I fix this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by putting 'localtime' modifier while getting current time.

```
SELECT strftime('%s','now', 'localtime') - strftime('%s', entrydate) FROM entities;
```